# think or swim not working on 12.04 or 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

I recently allowed the auto upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04.  Consequently ThinkOrSwim stopped working.  I re-installed thinkorswim, ubuntu 12.04 and wine.  Still it does not work.  I have seen in the blogs that the latest upgrade to thinkorswim is the cause.  Any suggestions on how to get it working again will be vastly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried PlayOnLinux - it's a little glitchy, but runs pretty good on Ubuntu 14.04, Mint 17 and Zorin 9.

I am new to Linux - testing out Ubuntu 14.04, Mint 17 and Zorin 9 for three weeks finally got ThinkorSwim working. From what I have been able to determine is it worked fine on earlier versions of Ubuntu as a Java program - TDameritrade has made some changes in the past few years and this is no longer the case.

I have tried the majority of the suggestions offered on this and other boards with no success. For me - I would get the installing updates screen and it would hang there (white color) then starting again same screen, but black color. Never would get to log on screen. Tried Wine with exe file - it didn't work either.

It ran best on Ubuntu and plus side Charts on my second monitor are better resolution than Windows 7 - two days now - I have not fired up Windows at all.

Comment: Welcome! Sorry to say that this post is very unclear/hard to read - if it contains an anser, it should explain it more concise and to the point. (You could just post another answer with a shorter form if you like.)

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me, but I had  to reinstall it "for this user only".  That puts it in your home directory.  I am running the latest ToS on Ubuntu 14.04.